# Spring Security Single Sign On in Windows Environment

Tags: spring, active-directory, spring-security, kerberos, spnego

I have a feeling I've stumbled into a technical black hole.  There have been many questions and not many (recent) answers out there.

Short summary:

I have a Windows environment operating with a domain controller and Active Directory implementation (soon to be operating with Quest's Authentication Services).  I have a series of Spring-based web applications I want to deploy to this environment and we need them to operate seamlessly with Single Sign-On using the domain credentials.

It looked like the answer was this:

http://blog.springsource.org/2009/09/28/spring-security-kerberos/

I was informed by some of the local AD admins that ktpass, though, was an unsafe (principals and keys stored in plain-text file) and outdated solution.  Given the blog linked above is 3 years old, it was tough to argue.

Then I came across this:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?134465-JDK-7-0-and-Spnego-Extension-don-t-work!

Posted just a week or so ago, it looks like recent efforts to integrate SPNEGO extensions have shown that it's incompatible with JDK 7 and no longer supported!

It seems like this would be a common thing for people to want to do.  I'm surprised that with a framework as widespread as Spring that there's not a simple way to achieve this.  Is there another approach I haven't found in the documentation?

Thanks for any insights or suggestions.

Comment: Why don't you look at the LDAP provider from spring security as given in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84680/how-do-you-authenticate-against-an-active-directory-server-using-spring-security and spring documentation http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ldap.html

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am facing exactly the same requirement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [WAFFLE](http://dblock.github.com/waffle/).

> WAFFLE is a native Windows Authentication Framework consisting of two
>   C# and Java libraries that perform functions related to Windows
>   authentication, supporting Negotiate, NTLM and Kerberos. Waffle also
>   includes libraries that enable drop-in Windows Single Sign On for
>   popular Java web servers, when running on Windows.

It has a [tutorial](http://code.dblock.org/single-sign-on-spring-security-negotiate-filter-kerberos-ntlm-wwaffle) for using it with Spring Security.

Comment: Keep in mind the words here ".. when running on Windows.." - WAFFLE depends on native windows libraries on the box your webapp may be running on, so will fail at runtime on *non* Wintel servers.  It may seem obvious but it caught me out.  It worked fine on my Win7 dev environment but bombed when deployed to our Linux VMs.  Doh.