# Spring security configuration to authenticate ldap user

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, active-directory, spring-ldap

I've been working on Spring web application in our company which authenticates users from database. But we are wanted to use the active directory server in our company for this purpose instead of database. unfortunately, I have a trouble to connect to the server. 
Here is my spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">


    <beans:bean id="successHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/App/Index" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="failureHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/App/loginError" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/App/Login" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl">
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sas"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry"
            ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
    </beans:bean>

    <http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <intercept-url pattern="/Content/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/Desktop/New_Them/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/App/Index" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/App/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/clc/ClcLogPhon/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <custom-filter ref="concurrencyFilter" position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/App/Login" />
        <remember-me key="myAppKey" />
        <session-management
            session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas">
        </session-management>
        <csrf />
        <headers>
            <xss-protection />
        </headers>
    </http>
    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"
        secured-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true" />

    <beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
        <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/App/Login" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="256" />
    </beans:bean>

    <ldap-server id="ldapServer"
        url="ldap://192.168.1.143/dc=springframework,dc=org" />

    <authentication-manager>
        <ldap-authentication-provider server-ref="ldapServer"
            user-dn-pattern="uid={0},ou=people" />
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Actually I just removed the database related beans and then added the ldap-server and authentication-manager in order to make our application using the ldap for authentication. I'm using Spring 4.0.1 and Spring security 3.2.1, along with java 1.7. Although the web application starts up, any information which I entered in login page was rejected and I got an `Access is denied` error in my console in eclipse. 
Also, I changed the Ldap url to the wrong IP address just for testing if the application failed. But it didn't change at all. So, I doubt that it even trying to connect to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I didn't receive any answers here, I search to solve my problem. 
First of all, I should set the url just like my Active directory setting. For instance, I totally neglected the port address after the IP address which is 389 in default. Moreover, I changed the domain at the end of the url address to my specific active directory domain address.
At the end my url address changed to

```
 ldap://192.168.1.143:389/DC=myDomain,DC=org
```

Secondly, I should use the user name password to connect to the Ldap. so I change my spring-security.xml just like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">


    <beans:bean id="successHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/App/Index" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="failureHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/App/loginError" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/App/Login" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl">
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sas"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry"
            ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
    </beans:bean>

    <http auto-config="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <intercept-url pattern="/Content/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/Desktop/New_Them/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/App/Index" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/App/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/clc/ClcLogPhon/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <custom-filter ref="concurrencyFilter" position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/App/Login" />
        <remember-me key="myAppKey" />
        <session-management
            session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas">
        </session-management>
        <csrf />
        <headers>
            <xss-protection />
        </headers>
    </http>
    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"
        secured-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true" />

    <beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
        <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/App/Login" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="256" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="contextSource"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <beans:constructor-arg
            value="ldap://192.168.1.143:389/DC=myDomain,DC=org" />
        <beans:property name="userDn"
            value="CN=username,CN=Users,DC=myDomain,DC=org" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="password" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
                <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                <beans:property name="userDnPatterns">
                    <beans:list>
                        <beans:value>uid={0},ou=users</beans:value>
                    </beans:list>
                </beans:property>
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
                <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                <beans:constructor-arg value="ou=groups" />
                <beans:property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="ou" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider"/>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

All in all, I totally recommend to use [JXplorer](http://jxplorer.org/) to connect to the Ldap at first .